# ERROR_PROCEDURE() returning NULL for code executed by SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

I have a stored procedure with a `TRY CATCH` statement and within that `TRY CATCH` I am calling another stored procedure which is throwing an error. An exception is thrown and caught however if the error is within the called stored procedure this is not shown in the `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` it is set to NULL. It seems the reason is due to Dynamic SQL being executed in the called stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROC dbo.MyError AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT,  XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            --do stuff here
            --SQL CODE
            SELECT 'HELLO' AS hello
            
            --then call sproc
            EXEC dbo.MyInnerError
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
           BEGIN
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
           END 
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
       END CATCH
END
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.MyInnerError AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQl nvarchar(50) = 'SELECT 1/0 as DYNAMIC_FAIL';
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQl;
END

EXEC dbo.MyError
GO
```

I have tried nesting the stored procedure in its own `TRY CATCH` but this leads to `TRANSACTION ROLLBACK` issues.

Is `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` NULL because it is out of scope? And is there a way to set this?

It seems the reason is due to Dynamic SQL being executed in called Stored procedure. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/sql-server-get-the-failed-stored-procedure-name-using-error_procedure/

Comment: Thats what i'm doing above but it is set to NULL, i am  calling a sproc with in a sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit based on updated question and comments**

[ERROR_PROCEDURE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188398.aspx) will not return a procedure name for SQL executed via SP_EXECUTESQL. Logically, if it did, it would return 'SP_EXECUTESQL' :). See this Connect entry "[TRY/CATCH: ERROR_PROCEDURE() does not report name of procedure if error occured in dynamic SQL](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/291982/msit-edw-try-catch-error-procedure-does-not-report-name-of-procedure-if-error-occured-in-dynamic-sql)", in particular this sentence in the response from Microsoft;

> Since there is no name associated with the ad hoc SQL, ERROR_PROCEDURE
>   will return NULL for errors raised from the execution level of the ad
>   hoc SQL.

---

I knocked up a very quick test and it works for me (SQL Server 2012);

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MyError AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT,  XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            --do stuff here
            --SQL CODE

            --then call sproc
            EXEC dbo.MyInnerError
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
           BEGIN
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
           END 
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
       END CATCH
END
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.MyInnerError AS
BEGIN
    ;THROW 51000, 'This is my only error.', 1;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.MyError
GO
```

Result is;

```
ErrorNumber ErrorSeverity ErrorState  ErrorProcedure   ErrorLine   ErrorMessage            
----------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ----------- ------------------------
51000       16            1           MyInnerError     4           This is my only error.
```

Comment: Okay that does work! Wonder why mine doesn't will investigate

Comment: @davey - yes, I'll add the results to my answer.

Comment: Okay mine isn't working because the called sproc is executing dynamic SQL by the look of it :(

Comment: Is the error occurring within the dynamic SQL? Can you expand your question with a simple demo?

Comment: Alter your MyInnerError sproc with this code: ALTER PROC dbo.MyInnerError AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQl nvarchar(50) = 'SELECT 1/0 as DYNAMIC_FAIL';
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQl;
END

Comment: Instead of using `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQl;` in your inner sproc can you get away with `EXEC @SQl;`? It's the sp_executesql that seems to be swallowing the error.

Comment: Unforturnately I have to use SP_EXECUTESQL  as it allows paramertised queries

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the sub-proc call to `MyInnerError` isn't failing; it is a call within `MyInnerError` that is failing but yet `MyInnerError` is completely successfully.

`MyInnerError` is completing successfully because you are not trapping the error and reporting a failure like you are doing in the outer proc via the `TRY` / `CATCH` structure.

That, and errors coming from Dynamic SQL will naturally never set `ERROR_PROCEDURE()`.

All of your procs should have the `TRY` / `CATCH` structure and the `CATCH` block should use either RAISERROR or THROW (depending on what version of SQL Server you are using) so that you can bubble the error up to the calling scope.

```sql
DECLARE @InNestedTransaction BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRY
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @InNestedTransaction = 1;
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
  END;

  ... one or more SQL statements ...

  COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@InNestedTransaction = 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;

  IF (ERROR_PROCEDURE() IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrState TINYINT = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrSeverity TINYINT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, @ErrSeverity, @ErrState);
    RETURN;
  END;

  ;THROW; -- introduced in SQL Server 2012

  ---- If using SQL Server 2008, replace the above (from "IF" through "THROW")
  ---- with the following.
  -- DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
  -- RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, 16, 1);
  -- RETURN;
END CATCH;
```

The `IF (ERROR_PROCEDURE() IS NULL)` block is used to catch situations like this where there is no proc generating the error. Calling `;THROW;` by itself will bubble-up the current error info, which in this case is `NULL` for `ERROR_PROCEDURE()`.

---

If you want to test this yourself, just run the following SQL which creates 3 stored procedures, all of which use the structure shown above. The inner-most procedure (ErrorTest1) calls `sp_executesql` using `SELECT 1/0;` as the query. The "divide by zero" error is trapped by the TRY / CATCH. The `ERROR_PROCEDURE()` function returns `NULL` as it was Dynamic SQL that generated the error. So, `RAISERROR` is called (technically calling `;THROW 50505, @ErrMessage, @ErrState;` would work as well) to indicate to the calling process that the current proc generated an error.

**Test Setup:**

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'ErrorTest3') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE ErrorTest3;
END;
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'ErrorTest2') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE ErrorTest2;
END;
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'ErrorTest1') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE ErrorTest1;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ErrorTest1
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @InNestedTransaction BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRY
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @InNestedTransaction = 1;
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
  END;

  SELECT '1a';
  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1/0 AS [ForceError];';
  SELECT '1b';

  COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@InNestedTransaction = 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;

  IF (ERROR_PROCEDURE() IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrState TINYINT = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrSeverity TINYINT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, @ErrSeverity, @ErrState);
    RETURN;
  END;

  ;THROW; -- introduced in SQL Server 2012

END CATCH;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ErrorTest2
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @InNestedTransaction BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRY
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @InNestedTransaction = 1;
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
  END;

  SELECT '2a';
  EXEC dbo.ErrorTest1;
  SELECT '2b';

  COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@InNestedTransaction = 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;

  IF (ERROR_PROCEDURE() IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrState TINYINT = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrSeverity TINYINT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, @ErrSeverity, @ErrState);
    RETURN;
  END;

  ;THROW; -- introduced in SQL Server 2012

END CATCH;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ErrorTest3
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @InNestedTransaction BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRY
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @InNestedTransaction = 1;
  END;
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
  END;

  SELECT '3a';
  EXEC dbo.ErrorTest2;
  SELECT '3b';

  COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@InNestedTransaction = 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;

  SELECT ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS [ErrorProcedure],
         ERROR_STATE() AS [ErrorState],
         ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [ErrorSeverity];

  IF (ERROR_PROCEDURE() IS NULL)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrState TINYINT = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ErrSeverity TINYINT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, @ErrSeverity, @ErrState);
    RETURN;
  END;

  ;THROW; -- introduced in SQL Server 2012

END CATCH;
GO
```

**Run Test:**

```sql
EXEC dbo.ErrorTest3;
```

**Returns:**

5 result sets:

```
3a
2a
1a
<empty>
ErrorProcedure  ErrorState  ErrorSeverity
ErrorTest1      1           16
```

And in the "Messages" tab:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ErrorTest1, Line 36
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: Will a try catch in called sproc help identify sproc name Dynamic SQL errors?

Comment: @davey not only does it work, it's required...if you implement the code I posted in both procs you will see. ...the other answer is incorrect and only appears to work due to the test being invalid and not mirroring your scenario.

Comment: @davey I have updated with the test code that I used. You can run it and see that it works prior to updating your code.